# Problem with enabling FIPS

Tags: grub2

While in the process of hardening a new Ubuntu installation, I performed the basic steps of enabling FIPS as described [here](https://ubuntu.com/security/certifications/docs/fips-enablement). After rebooting, I found that /proc/sys/crypto didn't exist. Oddly, `sudo ua status` shows that fips-updates is enabled.

After troubleshooting, I ended up checking GRUB and found there were the following entries

- Ubuntu, with Linux 5.14.0-1054-oem
- Ubuntu, with Linux 5.14.0-1054-oem (recovery mode)
- Ubuntu, with Linux 5.14.0-1054-fips
- Ubuntu, with Linux 5.14.0-1054-fips (recovery mode)

When I try the fips version, the screen ends up going blank except for a blinking cursor at the top left. After a while, I get the following error
`[   66.724025] hdaudio hdaudioCOD2: Unable to bind the codec.`
and then it's hung. If I try the fips (recovery mode) version, I can enter a root shell and see that /proc/sys/crypto/fip_enabled exists, but it's set to 0.

Two questions.

1. Should a separate fips version have been created? The text of the above link doesn't mention that.
2. How can I fix the hdaudio problem?

If it helps, I originally chose the `sudo ua enable fips` option and had the problem of /proc/sys/crypto not existing. So I next did `sudo ua enable fips-updates`.

The computer is a Dell Inspiron 3015.

Comment: The fips version are 5.4.0-1007 not 5.14.0-1054

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu. This time, being aware that a different kernel is created when executing 'sudo ua enable fips`, I knew to enter GRUB and choose the fips version. That worked.

So the problem may have been due to executing `sudo ua enable fips-updates` after first doing `sudo un enable fips`.